# Can I lock 2 tables at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking

I need to implement a locking scheme in my application. A user may only open a dialog/form, if it hasn't been locked. On the other hand a lock may only be set, if there is no dialog currently open, that corresponds to that lock.

My approach so far: 
I have a sql server table tbl_lock with column lockname where I maintain locks and a table tbl_dialog (user, dialogname) where I create a row whenever a user opens a dialog.

To create a lock I do the following:
1) Begin a transaction
2) select * from tbl_dialog with (SERIALIZABLE) where dialogname=@somename
3) insert a lock record for the dialog @somename in tbl_lock if the prio select returns no records
4) commit transaction

The problem ist, that I would also like to prevent that someone tries to open a dialog when some other user is trying to set a lock. I could repeat the above 4 steps and select tbl_lock with serializable and insert a record in tbl_dialog, but I fear the I run into a deadlock if 2 concurrent transactions execute step thus locking both tables tbl_dialog and tbl_lock at the same time.

Could I lock both tables in step 2 at once? Is there a smarter way to solve this problem?

Best Regards,
Sascha

EDIT:
Based on Bogdan's comment I would implement the following SP to set a lock:

```
Create procedure CreateLock 
    @dialogname nvarchar(10),
    @lockname nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @result int;
    DECLARE @locksuccess int = 0;

    begin tran;

    EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'myapplockmanagement', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockTimeout=3000;
    if @result>=0
    BEGIN
        -- Ensure no user has opened the dialog @lockname
        if not EXISTS(select 1 from tbl_dialog where dialogname=@dialogname)
        BEGIN
            if not EXISTS(select 1 from tbl_lock where lockname=@lockname)
            BEGIN
                insert into tbl_lock (lockname) values (@lockname);
                set @locksuccess = 1;
            END
        END
        commit;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        rollback;
    END

    return @locksuccess;
END
```

If I understood sp_getapplock correctly,  myapplockmanagement will be locked exclusively thus locking all other threads out. If the application lock could be aquired I can safely check my tbl_dialog and eventually insert a new row in tbl_lock, right?

So the next Procdure would be:

```
Create procedure RegisterDialogUsage 
    @dialogname nvarchar(10),
    @lockname nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @result int;
    DECLARE @registersuccess int = 0;

    begin tran;

    EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'myapplockmanagement', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockTimeout=3000;
    if @result>=0
    BEGIN
        -- Ensure that no lock is set.
        if not EXISTS(select 1 from tbl_lock where lockname=@lockname)
        BEGIN
            insert into tbl_dialog (dialogname) values (@dialogname);
            set @registersuccess = 1;
        END
        commit;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        rollback;
    END

    return @registersuccess;
END
```

So, if I am not mistaken these two SPs do exactly what I like:

1. Locks can only be set in tbl_lock, if there are no users are registered in tbl_dialog
2. Dialog usage can only be registerd in tbl_dialog if not lock ist set in tbl_lock
3. Thanks to sp_getapplock there wont't be concurrency problems.

Is that right?
(Corresponding SPs for removing the entries in tbl_lock and tbl_dialog had to be implemeted two...)

Sascha

Comment: Where does this application run? On a server or on multiple client machines? How do you plan to handle an abandoned lock, e.g. when ann application closes unexpectedly?

Comment: Right, I wasn't specific enough. The apps is a .Net application running on multiple client machines all connected to the same sql server. Abandoned locks are no problem, because I save the sql connection id with the entries in tbl_lock. Thus I can check if the connection is still alive via sys.dm_exec_sessions and if so the lock is not abandoned.

Comment: @Sascha: I would use a single table : dbo.Lock(DialogName, LockName). In this case I would create an unique/primary constraint on `(DialogName, LockName)`. Thus, for every dialog I can't have two or more locks with the same `LockName`. In this case, [1] these app locks will prevent duplicate keys, [2] you need just one procedure not two. Also, you need to release these locks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use application locks:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2007/05/07/using-application-locks-to-implement-a-critical-section-in-t-sql-code.aspx

Comment: I added an example implemation in im original post. Is that the way you ment it?